# How to prevent renaming of file in Camel when Exception is thrown in Process?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm having a bit of an issue with preventing the original file from being renamed when I throw/catch an Exception in a Processor.

I have a route like this:

```
<route customId="true" id="localRoute">
    <from uri="{{ftp.pull.LOCAL.server}}" />
    <process ref="Processor" />
    <to uri="{{ftp.push.LOCAL.route}}" />
</route>
```

The from URI includes the option of:  `&move=${file:name.noext}.${file:name.ext}.old`

And during my Process, I stop the Exchange from being routed to the end under certain conditions and also throw an Exception that I catch using:

```
<onException>
    <exception>com.myException.ThrownException</exception>
    <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
</onException>
```

Is there any way to prevent the renaming of the original file I'm pulling from if I throw and catch that exception?

(I throw and catch that Exception in order to prevent a file from entering a Idempotent File Repository for other routes. Many routes use this Processor.)

Comment: What happens if you don't handle the exception? Does it still rename the file if an exception is thrown?

Comment: If I remove the whole onException block, it doesn't rename the files and prints the big error message into the logs

Comment: Do you want the file to remain (you can use moveFailed) to move only the failed files somewhere? Is it that you need to handle the exception? In other words: Camel would not know that it failed?

Comment: I didn't want the files moved anywhere.  Basically what I'm thinking I'm looking for is the equivalent to a rollback, if using "move" then don't rename the file or if using an Idempotent File Repo don't put the name in to the Repo.  Basically act like the file wasn't polled this time, if that makes sense?

Comment: I think the problem lies in the handle part. If you handle the exception I am not sure the rollback occurs. You can instead of handling the exception do a try catch and if you catch the exception then just log or create a response or something. That should prevent the renaming.

Comment: Sorry, try/catch where?  In Spring or during the Processor that throws the Exception?  Because try/catching it in the Processor results in the file being renamed/file name being placed in the File Repo

Comment: Yeah, similar to your own answer below, dotry and docatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I may have found an answer.

So what I have found out is that by doing a global `<onException>` block that catches my custom Exception, it will prevent logging a stack trace and entering in a file name into the File Repo for routes that use a Idempotent File Repository.  But that global block will not prevent the routes that rename files from renaming the files.

In order to catch the Exception and prevent the logging of the stack trace on routes that rename files, I needed to use the doTry/doCatch blocks. I have to do something like this:

```
<route customId="true" id="localRoute">
    <from uri="{{ftp.pull.LOCAL.server}}" />
    <doTry>
        <process ref="Processor" />
        <doCatch><exception>com.myException.ThrownException</exception></doCatch>
    </doTry>
    <to uri="{{ftp.push.LOCAL.route}}" />
</route>
```

So my solution ends up looking like this:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <onException>
        <exception>com.myException.ThrownException</exception>
        <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
    </onException>
    <route customId="true" id="localRoute">
        <from uri="{{ftp.pull.LOCAL.server}}" />
        <doTry>
            <process ref="Processor" />
            <doCatch><exception>com.myException.ThrownException</exception></doCatch>
        </doTry>
        <to uri="{{ftp.push.LOCAL.route}}" />
    </route>
    <route customId="true" id="otherRoute">
        <from uri="{{ftp.pull.OTHER.server}}" />
        <setHeader headerName="otherFileRepoKey">
            <simple>${file:name}-${file:modified}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <idempotentConsumer messageIdRepositoryRef="otherFileStore">
            <header>otherFileRepoKey</header>
            <process ref="Processor" />
            <to uri="{{ftp.push.OTHER.route}}"/>
        </idempotentConsumer>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

File will be renamed unless you remove the `<handled>` or mark that as false.

If you handle the exception it won't propagate and your file component thinks that the Camel exchange processed successfully and it will rename the file.

Comment: Is there no way to then avoid the stack trace it then prints out in my logs?  Because I know from time to time this Exception I'm throwing will occur, so I'd rather not have large stack traces printed out.